# Launch shell script from PDF generated from LaTeX

Tags: shell, pdf, latex

i am new to stackoverflow, so apologies if i'm not posting in the right place.
Please help me with this one:
I want to launch a shell script from within the pdf generated from latex. I searched over internet all possibilities, but no luck.
my tex file look like:

`\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \href{run:/home/ankit/Desktop/document/a.sh}{Launch the script}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}`

The shell script "a.sh" looks like this:

`#!/bin/bash
    gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c 'ls; exec $SHELL'"`

i've already done:
1. chmod +x a.sh
2. change behavior of *.sh to execute in terminal on single click.
3. tried adobe reader and evince for linux/ubuntu.
4. when i click in evince i don't see anything but busy cursor sign which disappears after a while, but when launched evince from the terminal as evince document.pdf i see this error message:

**(nautilus-autorun-software:4318): WARNING **: Unable to find device for URI: Containing mount does not exist.**

Please help.
Thanks in advance.